# MongoDB: how to get the last values of two collections in a script?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, spagobi

I am using SpagoBI with MongoDB.
like mentioned in the link [1] I can use script .js on my MongoDB data base to get results.
What I need to do is to merge the two following queries results:

```
var query1=db['cygnus_/kurapath_enocean_switch2a_enocean'].find().sort({ recvTime : -1 }).limit(1) ;
var query2 = db['cygnus_/kurapath_enocean_switch2b_enocean'].find().sort({ recvTime : -1 }).limit(1);
```

If I put something like

```
var query= query1 + query2;
```

I got the error:

```
query has no method 'forEach' at serializeResult
```

Any ideas how to do that?
Thanks in advance for your help!

[1] http://wiki.spagobi.org/xwiki/bin/view/spagobi_server/data_set

Comment: What are you expecting as results for both queries ?
A single object (type ?), an array .. ?

Comment: an array containing the results of the two queries

Comment: can you try `var query= query1.concat(query2);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var results = query1.toArray().concat(query2.toArray());
```

What happens here is that `toArray()` is used to convert the result cursors into standard Javascript arrays of documents (in this case arrays with just one entry because you used `limit(1)`). Then the standard Javascript array method `concat` is used to append one array to the other and store it in the new array `results`.

That array can then be used as you want.